# How to not reload page on error ( Change Display:none value on Page post to iteself)

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I have a jsp which has a Div  with a form which is hidden on page load and is shown when user clicks on register button. The user provides data and clicks on submit button.My issue is if there are any errors present in the form data provided and the errors are to be displayed to the user , the page is getting reloaded with the form div being hidden rather than displaying the form with errors.

I have a landing page on which User is shown 2 links namely., APPLY and LOGIN. 
Based on the link the user clicks, a flag is set in the get parameters in the url and the Registration page is shown to the user. If the user clicked on apply, the user is shown the application page on registration and if they clicked on login page the user is shown the dashboard page.

On the Registration page load, the Login Module is displayed to the user which is basically your simple username and password and a button is present for account creation or registration. When user clicks on Register, the register button  and the login module are hidden and the Account creation form is shown to the user.

My issue is  when the user provides incomplete answers or provides username which already exists then errors need to be displayed to the user. But on page load on doing the post , the initial view of Login module and register button is shown to the user rather than the account form.The user has to click on Register button in order to view the form and the errors associated with each field. I was hoping whether there was an option of toggling the javascripts from the MVC controller based on the presence of errors in the form to display the account creation form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways, you can handle it.

1. Try using ajax to do form validation and populate errors instead of
   using form submit.
2. If the above is not an option, then you have to display the hidden div on page load using jquery or window.onload. You can check if there are errors and based on that call a function to enable the hidden div.

There are plenty of examples out there to check for conditions and enable a div.

Comment: I have gone the Ajax route but it complicates stuff rather than simplify and solve the issue. I will give more info to my question.

Comment: Did you try the second option?  I just provided options as an answer for your questions. You can post the issue that you are running into as a separate question, so that it is easy to answer by other folks as well. If my answer helped you, please accept it or upvote it. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that .I forgot to add that I was going to look into the second option. Thanks for your help.